# Compiling MySQL on Windows with C++ Builder

Tags: mysql, c++builder, compilation

Possible? To crazy to contemplate? if yes and no (respectively) any idea how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible.  With newer versions of Builder and some probably not-insignificant effort, I'd guess it probably is.  But why on earth would you want to?  You'll end up with a version of MySQL compiled in an untested environment instead of the distribution versions provided by MySQL themselves that gain lots of testing exposure.  I can't think of a single advantage of doing this, but I can think of plenty of disadvantages.

If your problem is that Builder is the only development environment you have to hand, be aware that you can compile using Visual C++ Express, which MS will give you for free.

If you really want to go about doing this, you'll be wanting [MySQL's build guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-sourcebuild-excerpt/5.1/en/index.html) and [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).  Following their instructions for Visual Studio will work to get you something you can start building.  You'll then need to hack around looking for appropriate compiler options and so forth.

Comment: The only reasons I am contemplating it is because of familiararity with the IDE plus the out of the box inclusion of very good libraries such as Boost and even the VCL. However you are right in that, if these benefits are very outweighed by the disadvantages, I'll just suck it up and use VS.

Comment: Unless you're planning on developing on MySQL (or its interfaces) itself, I'd suggest just using the libraries and binaries provided by MySQL AB and not compiling at all.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too challenging; just use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) if you'd like to compile it.